# Update Trigger only update if the data has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a update trigger that updates null records when a record is update in another table. My problem is that the data is in a gridview, and when you update it runs a update query on all the records in the grid not just the updated record. So when the trigger fires it updates every row in the target table that matches but I only want to update the one that data has changed. here is my trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_update_DeSchedule] ON [dbo].[tBatchDetails] 
    After UPDATE ,INSERT
AS    

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @BatchId int
          , @Ethanol varchar(10)
          , @Glucose varchar(10)
          , @SampleAge varchar(10);

    SELECT @BatchId = B.[BatchID]
        ,@Ethanol = [Ethanol]
        ,@Glucose= [Glucose]
        ,@SampleAge = SA.SampleAge  
    from INSERTED bd
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tSampleAge] sa ON SA.SampleAgeID = BD.SampleAge 
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tBatch] b ON B.ID =BD.ID

    UPDATE [dbo].[DeSchedule] 
    SET [Ethanol] = @Ethanol
      , [Glucose] = @Glucose
      , [SampleCompleted] = 1 
    WHERE [BatchID] = @BatchId 
        AND [SampleAge] = @SampleAge 
        AND SiteID = 6 
        AND SampleCompleted IS NULL

END
```

How can I in this trigger only update the record that data has changed in?

Comment: [**Try having a look at instead-of triggers**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

First thing you should do is separate your insert and update triggers. Doing them in a single trigger almost always causes problems. It is certainly going to cause you problems here. The code you posted should do what you are looking for when you insert.

However, when you update you need add a join to deleted. And then you will need to add where predicates for every column in the base table. The only way to know if the actual value has changed is to compare the values from inserted and deleted.

Something like this:

```
i.ColA <> d.ColA 
OR i.ColB <> d.ColB
etc...
```

Some may say to use the UPDATE function but this will NOT work for you. It returns true if the column is in the list of values being updated. It does NOT care if the value is the same as before.

And your current trigger is using scalar values. This is not a good approach as the trigger fires once per operation. Your code needs to be set based.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is fired for each Update statement not for each row in an update statement, you using Variables in your Trigger will fail/corrupt data when there is an update updating more than one row.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_update_DeSchedule] ON [dbo].[tBatchDetails] 
    After UPDATE ,INSERT
AS    

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Correct the Alias in the set clause I am not sure what is coming from where
    UPDATE S                    
     SET  S.[Ethanol] = [Ethanol]
        , S.[Glucose] = [Glucose]
        , S.[SampleCompleted] = 1  
    from INSERTED bd
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tSampleAge] sa ON SA.SampleAgeID = BD.SampleAge 
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[tBatch]     b  ON B.ID =BD.ID
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[DeSchedule] s  ON s.[BatchID] = B.[BatchID] 
                                         AND s.[SampleAge] = BD.SampleAge 
    WHERE SiteID = 6 
      AND SampleCompleted IS NULL

END
```

Comment: Why are we joining on DeSChedule when that is the table we are trying to update the record in?

Comment: @llerdal google `SQL Server Syntax for Update with joins` Thanks

Comment: Makes it easier to update because of the JOIN to the table you are updating.

Comment: This still updates the sample completed column for every record even if the ethanol and glucose is null. @M.Ali